# There's a "1" at the left side of the site. I do not know where it came from

Tags: php, html, mysql

```html
<form id="frmContact" method="POST" action="Pass2.php">
<p color="red" class="validate_msg"><font color="red">Please fix the errors below!</font></p>
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo (isset($gresult) ? $gresult["id"] :  ''); ?>" />
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <label for="regname">Applicant Name: </label><span class="val_regname"></span>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" name="name" 
        value="<?php echo (isset($gresult) ? $gresult["name"] :  ''); ?>" 
        id="name" class="txt-fld"/>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <label for="prices">prices: </label><span class="val_prices"></span>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" name="prices" 
        value="<?php echo (isset($gresult) ? $gresult["prices"] :  ''); ?>" 
        id="prices" class="txt-fld"/>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <label for="day">day #: </label><span class="val_day"></span>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" name="day" 
        value="<?php echo (isset($gresult) ? $gresult["day"] :  ''); ?>" 
        class="txt-fld"/>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <label for="slot">slot : </label><span class="val_slot"></span>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" name="slot" 
        value="<?php echo (isset($gresult) ? $gresult["slot"] :  ''); ?>" 
        class="txt-fld"/>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <label for="flag">Secondary School: </label><span class="val_flag"></span>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" name="flag" 
        value="<?php echo (isset($gresult) ? $gresult["flag"] :  ''); ?>" 
        class="txt-fld"/>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<input type="hidden" name="action_type" value="<?php echo (isset($gresult) ? 'edit' :  'add');?>"/>
<div style="text-align: center; padding-top: 30px;">
  <input class="btn" type="submit" name="save" id="save" value="Save" />
  <input class="btn" type="submit" name="save" id="cancel" value="Cancel" 
    onclick=" return GotoHome();"/><br>
  <br>
</div>
</form>
```

There's a "1" at the left side of the site. I do not know where it came from. The "1" only appear when I update. Can anyone help me find where the "1" came from?

Comment: Please share screenshot of your website and share full html page.

Comment: it is a small typographical error, check it yourself... in your code...

Comment: I don't see any `1`

Comment: how can i share a picture here?

Comment: Inspect the Element on your webpage to find where the 1 is.

Answer (score 0):

You have likely put a `1` somewhere in your code outside of a PHP tag, or you have `echo`'d out a boolean value. First do a search through your own code for `1`, otherwise look for any strings before `<?php` or random `echo` calls.